# pass 'this' to callback in a class ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript, callback, ecmascript-6, this

I have a Class in ecmascript 6 . I need to pass a value of 'this' to a callback.

I tried using .bind(this). So far does not seem to work. I also tried setting var _this  = this;  and using _this within the callback. it still does not work

```
     class Modal {
        constructor(modal) {
        this._modal = modal;
        this.id = this._options.id;      
       }
    }

    open(opts) {
        let modalOptions = {
            size: opts.size || '',
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: function controller($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                    var _this = this; 
                    this._options = {
                        id: opts.id
                    };
                    this.hcbuttons: [{id: '1', name: 'test'}, {id: '2', name: 'abc'}];
                    publisher.subscribe('triggered', this._options.id, function(event, creator) {
                        //as soon as we subscribe to the published event
                        var result = this.hcbuttons.filter(function( obj ) {
                            return obj.id == creator;
                        })[0];
                        if(result.sync === true) {
                            console.log('disabledall');
                        }                         
                    }).bind(this);


        }

}
```

Comment: what do you want that this to be?

Comment: the modalinstance, i basically want to pass 'this.hcbuttons' to the callback

Comment: @looneytunes, please fix the indentation and the brackets first, then explain what you've actually built there. Then we can talk on the same level

Comment: `this.hcbuttons: [{id: '1', name: 'test'}, {id: '2', name: 'abc'}];` is not valid syntax. If you want `this` to refer to the `Modal` instance, then you need to call `var _this = this;` in a context where `this` refers to the index (which is certainly not in the `controller` function).

Answer (score 3):

You are wrongly binding the `this`. You are calling the bind over the returned value of `subscribe` function. *Function* object only has the function `bind` in its *prototype*. So chance your code from this `}).bind(this);` to `}.bind(this))`.

Since you want to set `this` as the modal class,

```
 //change one
 open(opts) {
        var _this = this;
        let modalOptions = {
 //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 //change two
 }.bind(_this));
```

Comment: tried it , still does not work @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @looneytunes If you want `modalOptions` to be the `this`  inside of that event then my first suggestion would work. If you want the `Modal` to be the `this` then use my second suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ES2015, why not use **lambdas** (arrow functions)? They bind this automatically

```
open(opts) {
  let modalOptions = {
    size: opts.size || '',
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    controller: function controller($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
      this._options = {
        id: opts.id
      };
      this.hcbuttons = [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'test'
      }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'abc'
      }];
      publisher.subscribe('triggered', this._options.id, (event, creator) => {
        let result = this.hcbuttons.filter(obj => obj.id === creator)[0];
        if (result.sync) {
          console.log('disabledall');
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can read more on arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions and how they work (might help you in the future).